# Webkit rendering bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions

So i got this transitioned scaling on hover, but sometimes theese strange bugs appear.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0dlG.png
I've read something about putting a z-index value will fix it, but it doesn't. This appears in Chrome. When looking in Canary, the bugs doesn't appear, but do anyone have a temporary solution?

```
.menu-item {
    transition: transform ease .25s;
}

.menu-item-wrap:hover .menu-item {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: you want us to diagnose it without seeing your actual code?

Comment: Are you sure it's a webkit bug?
If yes, you could submit it to webkit bugzilla.